# Images not scaling with css auto width

Tags: css, image, height, scaling

I've put the following code in my page:

```css
image {
    margin: 0 2px 0 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: auto !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I want to scale all images to max height of 100px, and have the browser to adjust their height accordingly. But the result is that the images are only cropped to 100px height with rest of them hidden.

What should I do to achieve the scaling effect? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try changing `height` to `max-height`

Comment: I've already tried it but without effect :(

Comment: What is image? Is this a class applied to `<img>`? or something else. Can you provide some of your HTML?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wVu8x/

Comment: Yes, it's a class. In fact, it's a part of a Wordpress plugin showing Facebook action feed on my blog. Here's how it looks in the page code:
    <p class="ik_fb_facebook_image">

Comment: I've updated JSFiddle with a part of the page code. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

use img for image not image to apply styles on in it

```
img{your style here}
```

Comment: Hmmm... "Image" is a part of the Wordpress plugin code I'm struggling to style. I'm afraid that may be difficult. See here: jsfiddle.net/wVu8x

Comment: add classes in image tags or you can target image tag with their parent class i.e .parentclass img{ your style}, or you can use :nth-child selector..

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired effect with the following:

```
img {
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

You do not need the overflow, text-align, or width properties. You can keep the margin properties, but the code above addresses your question.

Comment: Unfortunately when I remove text-align, the image gets aligned left and when I remove overflow, the image is under the text.|
Only removing width attribute gives no effect.

Comment: What is the HTML that you're using?